# How can I edit a photo in a shortcut before sharing it

Tags: ios, shortcut, shortcuts-app

I have a shortcut that snaps the screen and shares via WhatsApp. However if I try to crop the image in WhatsApp before sending, the screen ‘glitches’ and the crop is discarded. The same happens if I try to share via messenger. I’ve tried adding a crop stage as well. I’m using iOS17.3.

How can I edit the photo before sending?

[image: screenshot of stages in shortcut: take screenshot, crop, send]

Comment: Are you trying to crop the screenshot manually and where are the recipients listed